# I am unable to enable wireless networks. How can I enable it?

Tags: 12.10, wireless, networking, hp-pavilion

I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed on an hp pavillion dv5 laptop I can't enable wireless networks. I am able to connect to wired networks though. I have a wireless button that's currently set on disabled, and when I try to enable it through the button, nothing happens! What do I need to do to enable my wireless network?

From `lspci | grep 802`, I got nothing. From `lspci`, I got the following relevant output:

```
08:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
```

From Software sources, it doesn't show any additional drivers.

From [here](http://linux.aldeby.org/post/Ubuntu-Linux-on-HP-Pavilion-Part-5-Wireless.html), I use Atheros AR928X but I don't know where to put the blacklist stuff into.

Comment: What does `lspci | grep 802` reveal? Is it activated in BIOS?

Comment: mmmh... did you try to install drivers from additional drivers...  check out this website, it might help  [link](http://linux.aldeby.org/post/Ubuntu-Linux-on-HP-Pavilion-Part-5-Wireless.html)

Comment: What is the output of `lsmod | grep ath`?

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the wireless adapter actually works (for example, can you try it under a Windows installation?), your options may be limited.  I had a nearly identical experience with an HP Envy dv6 7200, and posted a number of potential solutions that I tried for enabling wireless (see [How do I turn on wireless adapter on HP Envy dv6 7200 under Ubuntu (any version)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225898/how-do-i-turn-on-wireless-adapter-on-hp-envy-dv6-7200-under-ubuntu-any-version)).  After several days of futzing around with it, I finally returned it an bought a Dell Inspiron instead (works great with Ubuntu 12.04).

You might find it useful to step through the solutions I tried and see if any of them work for your model.

If your laptop is no longer under warranty, you can try messing with the actually wireless card itself (see Solution 3 in the above link, as well as the answer that follows).  Apparently people do have success with this approach, but obviously it's more involved and possibly risky.

Good luck!